# javascript, if condition optimization

Tags: javascript

I want to improve more than one "if and else if". I have the conditions mentioned below, but I'm annoyed because I'm doing too many "repeats". How can I fix this?

```
const locale = window.location.origin;
const pathName = window.location.pathname;
let lang = pathName.toString().split("/")[1];

if (lang === "")
  lang = "tr"
else if (lang === "en")
  lang = "en"
else if (lang === "ar")
  lang = "ar"
else if (lang !== "tr" || "en" || "ar")
  lang = localStorage.getItem('VueAppLanguage')

console.log(lang)

const res = await axios.get(locale + '/' + lang + '/categories')
```

Comment: just for the sake of better abstraction I would use a map pairing locale path values to language in case they don't always perfectly match, and I would simply grab the language mapped to the current locale, if any, otherwise `localStorage.getime('VueAppLanguage')`. I was writing such answer but I see you already got working solutions in the response queue

Comment: By the way, `lang !== "tr" || "en" || "ar"` will be alwqys truthy. Boolean operators don't work like that! Should be `lang !== "tr" && lang !== "en" && lang != "ar"` or `!["tr", "en", "ar"].includes(lang)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If `pathName.toString().split("/")[1]` is empty, then set "tr" as default value
2. Check if lang is any of the standard languages.

```
const locale = window.location.origin;
const pathName = window.location.pathname;
let lang = pathName.toString().split("/")[1] || "tr";       // 1
let noStandardLanguage = !["tr","en","ar"].includes(lang);  // 2

if (noStandardLanguage)
  lang = localStorage.getItem('VueAppLanguage')

console.log(lang)

const res = await axios.get(locale + '/' + lang + '/categories')
```

Comment: the error i got
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inline')
    at ContentFiltering.apply (include.preload.js:2287:18)`

Comment: Based on the code you posted, it I guess it's `await axios.get(locale + '/' + lang + '/categories')` that throws that error. You need to add breakpoints to see why `lang` or `locale` is undefined. What does `localStorage.getItem('VueAppLanguage')` return, for example?

Comment: all my conditions are working as i stated above.
but when I use your codes that I don't understand, I get the error I said. I'm trying to find where the error is coming from.

Comment: I understand the error, but I have no idea how to solve it.
Error:
When you manually change the `VueAppLanguage` value in "Local Storage" and refresh the page, this causes the "above mentioned" error.

Comment: Well, it's weird if your original code doesn't generate the same error, because it should be the same (not true: your code always read from VueAppLanguage). I also have no idea what you changed VueAppLanguage to, and why you even have that kind of code. If you only want to allow "tr", "en", "ar" as languages, then the code shouldn't look like that, but that wasn't what you asked for. Also, I have no idea what parameters that are allowed in the api call because the original code never explained it.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a default value and check against known languages.

```
lang ||= "tr";

if (!['ar', 'en', 'tr'].includes(lang)) lang = localStorage.getItem('VueAppLanguage');
```

---

The expression

```
lang !== "tr" || "en" || "ar"
```

does not work like intended, because the comparison

```
lang !== "tr"
```

checks only the first string, and never the other for comparison.

A value with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) check is the left hand side (lhs) is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), like a not empty string, or others (please see link) and takes only the next value if the lhs is [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), the opposite of *truthy*.

For comparing a list (here an array) of values, you could take [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: the error i got
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inline')
    at ContentFiltering.apply (include.preload.js:2287:18)`

Comment: sorry i can not help.

Comment: I understand the error, but I have no idea how to solve it.
Error:
When you manually change the `VueAppLanguage` value in "Local Storage" and refresh the page, this causes the "above mentioned" error.

Comment: i have no experience in local storrage and promises, sorry.